# unable to type any language in ckeditor when I select any other language other than english, just english letters display

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, arabic

unable to type any language character in ckeditor when I select any other language other than english, just english letters display.

http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/uilanguages.html

please guide regarding this

Comment: I think that changing the language just changes the language of the toolbar.

Comment: yes, it changes the toolbar language, but I get the solution for content. content language will be change from computer.

Answer (score 0):

[The SDK sample you quoted](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/uilanguages.html) and the feature it describes is about the **language of the user interface** (thus: the "Setting Editor UI Language" title). It has nothing to do with the language of your content.

See also the [Creating Multilingual Content](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/language.html) sample for some features that concern creating content in right-to-left languages or setting the language for text parts.